# Matlab does not see C++ compiler

Tags: c++, matlab

I've recently installed Matlab R2016a.

When I try to execute

```
mex -setup
```

I've got the following message:

```
Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found. You can install the freely available MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler; see Install MinGW-w64 Compiler. For
more options, visit http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/win64.html
```

I did check the list and it turned out that I do have all tools in my system that are compatible with this Matlab version. I also installed Windows SDK for Windows 10.

Doest anyone know what might be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: matlab only support 'professional' version. If you have community version, then you need to install MinGW as in the error message. http://kr.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2016a/index.html

Comment: I've got a professional version. However, I've just noticed that the size on the disk is like 240 MB, which seems for me a bit too small. Do you think my installation is broken then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I realised that Microsoft Visual Studio does not install C++ compiler through a express setup, which makes a lot of sense... I guess.

Comment: Yeah - been there, done that. You have to explicit select that :)